# Python: behave integration in setuptools' setup.py

Tags: python, bdd, setuptools, python-behave

I have written a small utility package for handling file permissions. The structure follows the [Python package standards](http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/):

```
.
|-- __init__.py                     # All the code is here, for now
`-- tests
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- permission_mode.feature     # Feature files for behave
    |-- steps                       
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   `-- steps.py                # Step files for behave
    `-- test_modtools.py            # Nose tests
```

Both nose and behave run the tests from the command line without issues:

**Nose:**

```
$ nosetests
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
```

**Behave:**

```
$ behave
Feature: Lots of cheese # permission_mode.feature:1

  Scenario: blah  # permission_mode.feature:2
    Given a       # steps/steps.py:1 0.000s
    Then b        # steps/steps.py:5 0.000s

1 feature passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
1 scenario passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
2 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m0.000s
```

My `setup.py` file contains the following test spec:

```
test_suite='nose.collector',
tests_require=['nose']
```

And therefore `python setup.py test` runs nose tests with the same output as `nosetests`.

**How do I configure behave as the package's test tool, so that `python setup.py test` will run behave?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at "setup.py" from behave.
It contains the usage of the colocated "setuptools_behave.py" test runner (and installs it).

**RECIPE FOR USAGE:**

```
# -- file:setup.py
from setuptools_behave import behave_test
...

setup(
    ...
    tests_require=["behave>=1.2.4"],
    cmdclass = {
        "behave_test": behave_test,
    },
    ...    
)
```

To verify it, execute "python setup.py --help-commands". It should contain a command "behave_test".
Otherwise, run "python setup.py behave_test --help".

Comment: Thanks!
I've added this to my setup.py, and had two problems: a. `behave_test` does not install the packages in `tests_require`, so I have to install `behave` manually. b. After installing behave, `python setup.py behave_test` gives `can't open file 'behave': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. This happens both with and without a virtual environment.

Comment: And thanks again for the attention. It's always a pleasure to get an answer from the actual developer.

Answer (score 1):

Look this commit [Provide simple test runner to run behave tests from setup.py](https://github.com/behave/behave/commit/056f3e7d57eed06f5754bd81618abc9fc63585a3#diff-3b6c0417e34e9f09eaf9989f5e6648c6).

Maybe for next release?

Comment: Thanks, that's good news. I have downloaded the latest code from github, and there are still some bugs with virtual environments. I tried hacking it a bit and changing `sys.executable` in line 124 to `os.path.dirname(sys.executable)`, but it didn't solve the problem. Will open a ticket.

https://github.com/behave/behave/blob/056f3e7d57eed06f5754bd81618abc9fc63585a3/setuptools_behave.py